# Fancy enumeration

Tags: numbering, enumerate

I'm trying to mirror or at least get something functionally similar to the below enumeration scheme, but have not had any success.

[image: Enumeration Example]

This is the closest I got.

```
\begin{enumerate}[label*=FR \arabic*.]

  \item The capture device system design shall capture a CubeSat.

  \begin{enumerate}[label*=DR \arabic*.]
\item First Subtopic

\item Second Subtopic

\begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.]

  \item First Sub-Subtopic

  \item Second Sub-Subtopic

\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is just playing aroud with the [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) optional arguments, including setting `leftmargin=*`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,pifont}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Some text before the list.

\begin{enumerate}[label={\bfseries FR \arabic*:},leftmargin=*]

  \item The capture device system design shall capture a CubeSat.

  \begin{enumerate}[label={\bfseries \ding{118}\quad DR \arabic{enumi}.\arabic*:},leftmargin=*]

  \item First Subtopic

    Some more information

  \item Second Subtopic

    \begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*.},leftmargin=*]

      \item First Sub-Subtopic

        Some more information

      \item Second Sub-Subtopic

    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```